# Why does the combination of remapping <esc> to <nop> cause strange characters to be automatically inserted when starting vim with startinsert?

Tags: vim

Here is my .vimrc:

```
inoremap <esc> <nop>
```

When I start vim using `vim +startinsert`, I get a buffer with the following strange characters inserted automatically (and, yes, I am in insert mode with the cursor after the 'c'):

```
[?1;2c
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `t_RV` option is set *Vim* uses it to ask the terminal about itself. Terminals will generally reply with a sequence that starts with Esc, and your insert mapping interferes with this response sequence: the initial Esc is “eaten”, and the rest seen as normal user input by *Vim*.

Are you using *rxvt* for your terminal emulator? Your output matches a sequence that the *Vim* source code indicates that *rxvt* sends in response to the xterm-default `t_RV` query (which Vim uses, even when `TERM=rxvt`).

You can clear `t_RV` (e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`) to avoid this particular problem.

```
set t_RV=
```

---

Your (un)mapping of Esc may make it particularly difficult to use any non-ASCII keys though: almost all other keys (arrows, Home, End, Page Up/Down, F1–F12, etc.) send sequences that start with Esc. Your mapping will probably interfere with *Vim* being able to recognize the sequences these keys send.

You may be interested in *Vim*’s “easy mode” (`vim -y`); it automatically starts in insert mode and adds mappings and other settings that make *Vim* mode like a “click-and-type” editor. See `:help -y` and `:help evim-keys` (you may need to type C-o first, if you are stuck in insert mode). If you are set on trying to avoid *Vim*’s modes, you might simply want to investigate a different style of editor.

Comment: I'm using Apple's terminal, which gives `xterm-256color` when I type `echo $TERM`. In any case `set t_RV=` worked! Note that you mistyped the command to `r_RV=`. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not interested in starting in insert mode except when writing commits. I'm also not interested in mapping <esc> to <nop> for the long term, just until I commit 'jk' to memory as the new mapping for escape.

Comment: @Jashugan You can do `nmap <expr> <Esc> (empty(getchar(1)) ? "" : "\e")`, it will have nearly the same effect, but won’t replace `<Esc>` with `<Nop>` if there are some characters in typeahead buffer.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say why exactly these characters are inserted, but `<Esc>` is the first character of *all* or almost all sequences used to transfer any data besides user input from terminal [emulator] to vim. Escape starts sequences used to tell about mouse clicks, `F1`…`F12` key presses, sometimes `<Del>` or `<BS>` (highly depends on the terminal, usually terminals outputs something else for this), arrow keys, `<PageUp>`/`<PageDown>`, information about size changes, …. Some of the data is processed as regular user input (note: in **any** case terminal will be using the same stream it uses to pass your input, there is just a difference in layer in C code where this input is being processed). When it is and you remap escape you see such strange characters.

Note that if you are trying to set up vim configuration which is always in insert mode you need `&insertmode` setting, not `:startinsert`. But it would be much better if you forget about vim, you don’t want vim if you don’t want normal mode being default one.

Comment: This is actually part of a Vimscript function I wrote in which I want to enter insert mode when writing a commit message. In all other situations I do start vim in normal mode. I did not know about `&insertmode` before.